# Find minimum number of iterations to reach a certain sum

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem since weeks, but couldn't arrive to a solution.
You start with two numbers X and Y both equal to 1. Only valid options are `X+Y` or `Y+X` at a time. We need to find minimum number of iterations need to reach a specific number.

eg : if the number is 5

```
X=1, Y=1; X = X+Y

X=2, Y=1; Y = X+Y

X=2, Y=3; Y = Y+X

X=2, Y=5; Stop answer reached
```

My take : If a number is odd let's say 23, decrement by 1. Now value = 22. Find the largest number that divides 22 = 11. Now reach the number by adding 1's so that:

```
X=11; Y=1 ; Y=Y+X

X=11; Y=12; X=X+Y

X=23, answer reached
```

But the problem with this approach is I cannot recursively reach a specific number, as even if I reach a certain point, say X = required value, the Y value gets misplaced and I cant reuse it to reach another value

Comment: May be ask this question on math site?

Comment: One observation: if you build a tree with possible distinct results after each step you will get {(1-1)} at 1 step, {(2-1)} at second, {(3-1),(2-3)} at third,
{(4-1),(3-4),(5-3),(2-5)} at fourth etc. The max value you get in each step is fibonacci numbers{1, 2, 3, 5, 8...}. As steps proceed all values are filled in each step from 1 to fibonacci number but on step 5 number 6 is missing, on step 6 you have all from 1 to 13 then in step 7 you have all from 1 to 21 but except 20. I didn't proceed more but it may be some known sequence {6, 20, ..} Don't know.

Comment: So my hypotesis would be that minimum number of steps to get required number equals to the height of that tree except those magical numbers(6, 20, ...) For example if you need to get number 67, then you find that it can't be before fibonacci number 55 but it probably will appear on next step where fibonacci is 89. So you get 10 steps as height of tree will be 10. For 5(is fibonacci) you get height 4, for 7 you get height 5 as 7 is between 5 and 8. But it is just a suggestion.

Comment: This is equivalent to finding n-th term of oeis sequence [A178047](http://oeis.org/A178047).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I can give an `O(nlogn)` solution.

The method seems like [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)

Use `f(x, y)` express the minimum number of iterations to this state. This state can be reached by `f(x-y, y)` if `x>y` or `f(x,y-x)` if `x<y`. We can see that the way to reach state `(x, y)` is unique, we can calculate it in `O(logn)` like [gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

The answer is `min( f(n, i) | 1 <= i < n)` so complexity is `O(nlogn)`

python code:

```
def gcd (n, m):
    if m == 0:
        return n
    return gcd (m, n%m)

def calculate (x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return -1
    return calculate (y, x%y) + x/y

def solve (n):
    x = 0
    min = n
    for i in xrange (1, n):
        if gcd (n, i) == 1:
            ans = calculate (n, i)
            if ans < min:
                min = ans
                x = i
    print min

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solve (5)
```

Comment: Why cannot we reach the state `(x, y)` with `x <= y` from state `(x-y, y)` ?

Comment: Because x ≤ y implies x - y ≤ 0.

Comment: You should mention that gcd (x, y) = 1 throughout the additions leading to the result n, because that allows for the condition gcd (n, i) = 1. If you remove the cases n ≤ 4 which require n-1 steps, you can assume n > i > n/2 and the number of steps is 1 + calculate (i, n - 1). If n is even i must be odd, so you can iterate through the odd i only, improving the speed.

Answer (score 4):

If the numbers are not that big (say, below 1000), you can use a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Consider a directed graph where each vertex is a pair of numbers `(X,Y)`, and from each such vertex there are two edges to vertices `(X+Y,Y)` and `(X,X+Y)`. Run a BFS on that graph from `(0,0)` until you reach any of the positions you need.

Comment: The range is upto 10000